# Why is this reply by Deputy Attorney General Rosenstein funny?

Tags: united-states, congress, law, espionage

During the congressional hearing of Deputy Attorney General Rod Rosenstein on June 28th, Mr. Rosenstein was asked the following question:

> Did you threaten to subpoena their [staffers on the House Intelligence Commitee] calls and emails?

To which Rosenstein replied:

> No sir, and there's no way to subpoena phone calls.

This answer prompted some laughter in the room, and was also [featured on a late night TV show](https://youtu.be/5gPVRc4taCg?t=54s) as a humorous reply.

English is not my first language, neither am I familiar with the US justice system, so the joke is not apparent to me.

**What makes Mr. Rosenstein's reply funny?**

Comment: The NSA has records and recordings of every phone call happening in the states. They could subpoena the call.

Comment: Humor is subjective; I'm not sure this question fits in its current format. If you're looking for an explanation as to why some found this funny, it's that a subpoena is an order to produce evidence (or appear in court). You could perhaps subpoena a phone company for records of calls (e.g. number XXX-XXXX called YYY-YYYY at 3:00pm), but "subpoena phone calls" itself doesn't make much sense, and hence the humor in the interrogative question (or the humor in relying on a "media source" also unable to make this distinction).

Comment: @user_42 Blatantly untrue, and sounds like anti-US propaganda to fail to make such a distinction. Snowden exposed NSA programs about them collecting [phone *metadata*](https://techcrunch.com/2018/05/04/nsa-triples-metadata-collection-numbers-sucking-up-over-500-million-call-records-in-2017/), which is exactly as I described above (e.g. one number called another). The only way some govt agency can listen to a US citizen's call is if they had a warrant to intercept communications, likely a FISA warrant. The **ease** of which the government can obtain such warrant is a hotly contested issue.

Comment: This is definitely off-topic for this site, though I'm not sure where you could find an answer(StackExchange doesn't have a comedy site, unfortunately). The gist is: "We heard you threatened to do X and Y, did you?", and the response "No, and Y is impossible anyway" implies the person asking the question is ill-informed.

Comment: @Giter: I thought about posting it on Law.SE because I assumed it would be about the nature of a subpoena and taking it too literally. But there might also have been some legislation about it that made the statement funny. Which, I think, falls within the scope of this site. But nevertheless, thank you for the answer!

Comment: This should be migrated to [ELL.SE](https://ell.stackexchange.com/). Questions like this are on-topic there (there's a subject-verb confusion that makes it amusing)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79584/discussion-between-user-42-and-c-helling).

Comment: Why is it on hold instead of being moved to English language stack exchange? (Although the answer is simple: The question uses subpoena as a verb. It is like saying "Did you arrest the calls and emails?" - "No, calls can't be arrested.")

Comment: @Thern, **it's not a question about English though**.  The joke was not funny because of a turn of phrase.  The exchange was somewhat funny because of known facts and beliefs about how the US government functions.  Which makes it appropriate for this site.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79669/discussion-on-question-by-pat3d3r-why-is-this-reply-by-deputy-attorney-general-r).